# Limiting the number of bars in a Histogram produced in SAS

Tags: sas, histogram, sgplot

I am running a proc sgplot in SAS to create a histogram. Y-axis: Number of people, X-Axis: Count of Miles. The problem is the histogram is displaying the data using 30+ bars of very small x-axis intervals. I want only 10 bars to display in the histogram.
Is there a simple feature I can add to the code to limit the histogram to display only 10 bars? Code below:

```
    proc sgplot data= miles;
    title "Cumulative Miles Driven by Number of Individuals"
    histogram CumulativeMiles/scale= count
    fillattrs=(color=blue);
    xaxis values= (0 to 1000 by 100)
    label= "Cumulatve Miles Driven"
    yaxis values= (0 to 50000 by 10000)
    label= "Number of Individuals";
    run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NBINS=10` option on the `HISTOGRAM` statement.

> NBINS=numeric-value specifies the number of bins. The system
> determines the BINWIDTH= value. The bins always span the range of the
> data.
>
> The procedure attempts to produce tick values that are easily
> interpreted (for example, 5, 10, 15, 20). The procedure sometimes
> adjusts the location of the first bin and the bin width accordingly.
> As a result, the number of bins shown in the plot might not exactly
> match the number specified with NBINS=.

Or specify the BINWIDTH and/or BINSTART options.
See the plot options [here](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=grstatproc&docsetTarget=n17xrpcduau1f8n1c1nhe477pv18.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).